# ASP.NET MVC shared web hosting recommendations? (Alternatively, good Windows VPS providers?)

Tags: windows, hosting, vps, .net

I am looking to deploy a small, low traffic website I've built using ASP.NET MVC that just allows it's users to fill out a form and upload a file (.doc, .docx, .pdf, .txt). The administration side of the site just allows people to create different forms for users to fill out.

So, all in all a very simple, low traffic CRUD ASP.NET MVC application with some file uploading and using a SQL DB as the backend. I'm having a hard time finding a good (any?) hosts that offer ASP.NET MVC though?

I would, if the price was right, go down the VPS route but I would really need it to be from a rock-solid provider. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post this answer and accept it because Generic Error's answer got me most of the way there but this was the step that "made things work".

1. Open your MVC application in Visual Studio 2008
2. Configure Visual Studio 2008 to deploy the MVC dll

   - Click "Show All Files" in Solution Explorer
   - Expand the References folder
   - Click System.Web.Mvc reference
   - In the property windows, select True in the "Copy Local" property
3. Publish the application via Visual Studio 2008

   - Click Build -> Publish to publish your application to a server using FTP

This is taken from the DiscountASP KB but I'm sure it applies to most sites. The end result was it placing the System.Web.MVC DLL in my bin folder but I like the fact it's a built in part of Visual Studio and not something I have to remember to do for each site.

Answer (score 6):

If you add the MVC DLLs to you bin directory it will host happily on any up to date ASP.Net host.  Personally I use an [Discount ASP.Net](http://discountasp.net/) and am very happy with them.

Comment: So am I correct in stating that any ASP.NET host offering .NET 3.5 will have a bin directory in my webroot and I just need to place the appropriate DLLs in there in order to use MVC functionality? Thanks for your help so far mate.

Comment: Almost.  Any ASP.Net site you create (including MVC sites) will have a bin folder in its root where you can place the .DLLs.  For example in my single hosting account I have 3 sites in different folders that each have their own bin directory.

Comment: I love DiscountASP.net, I'm with them since 2005 when they only had servers in US (I'm in Europe) and I must say... I developed a web app and hosted there ... we are getting so many 503's !! we are spending 60Gb bandwidth per day. So... for this scale, do not choose them!

Answer (score 1):

If your hosting provider already has ASP.NET MVC 1.0 installed on the hosting server, deploying your MVC application is no different that deploying any ASP.NET Web application. However, if the hosting provider does not currently support ASP.NET MVC 1.0, you must upload the required MVC assemblies in the Bin folder of your deployed application.
..
More informaiton please go to
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410407.aspx

If youi're looking for a hosting company who can support ASP.NET MVC, recommend
[www.webhost4life.org](http://www.webhost4life.org)